# Help in understanding one step in the proof of the chain rule

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation

Well, the chain rule is familiar to everyone. The theorem is expressed in my textbook as follows:

Let $g$ be a differentiable function on an open interval $I$ and let $f$ be a differentiable function on an open interval that contains the range of $g$. Then $f \circ g$ is differentiable on the interval $I$ and $(f \circ g)' (x) = f'(g(x)) · g'(x)$ for each $x ∈ I$.

Proof: We use the notation $∆t$ to stand for an increment in the variable $t$. Let us use the symbol $V(r)$ to stand for any expression which tends to $0$ as $∆r → 0$. Fix $x ∈ I$. Set $r = g(x)$. By hypothesis,

$$\lim_{\Delta r \to 0} \frac{f(r+ \Delta r)-f(r)}{\Delta r}=f'(r)$$

or

$$\frac{f(r+ \Delta r)-f(r)}{\Delta r}-f'(r)=V(r)$$

or  $f(r+ \Delta r)=f(r)+\Delta r f'(r)+\Delta r V(r)$ (*). Since $∆r$ in equation
($*$) can be any small quantity, we set $∆r = ∆x · [g'(x) + V(x)]$ . Substituting this expression into (6.7.1) and using the fact that $r = g(x)$ yields

$$f(g(x)+∆x[g′(x) + V(x)])$$

$$=f(r) + (∆x · [g'(x) + V(x)]) · f'(r) + (∆x · [g'(x) + V(x)]) · V(r)$$

$$= f(g(x)) + ∆x · f'(g(x)) · g'(x) + ∆x · V(x). \,(**)$$

I don't know how to get $**$ from the previous step. I believe my problem lies in the poor understanding of $V(x)$ and $V(r)$.